# Not Displaying Content In IE

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

This is my code in codeigniter application. In Mozilla the add_PM div will be overwritten by the content of the variable msg. But in IE the variable msg has content but the add_PM div is not overwritten. So nothing will be displayed. Is there is any problem in my code?

```
function addPjctMngr(){
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/addProjectManager",
    success: function(msg){
      $("#add_PM").html(msg).show();
    }  
  });
}
```

When I tried to use this code

```
$("#add_PM").html('');
$("#add_PM").html(msg).show();
```

Nothing will happen in IE.

Comment: any errors...? did you try to alert the msg...?

Comment: no errors.but trying to alert msg have content but not that displaying the "add_PM" div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought, check for html tags whether closed properly or not, that might be a problem as well in IE. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing your error but you may want to try the replaceWith function ( http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) instead and see if that accomplishes what you want.